# error parsing json to string

Tags: php, android, json

[image]Guys i am trying to connect my android app to php server and using json to encode data . I am unable to decode it on the app.
Please help

```
public class JsonDemoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     HttpPost httppost;

        StringBuffer buffer;

        HttpResponse response;

        HttpClient httpclient;
        TextView tv;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try{

             httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();

             httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/jsondemo.php"); // make sure the url is correct.



             response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

             HttpEntity he=response.getEntity();

             JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(he));

             String message=jo.getString("message");
             String from=jo.getString("from");
             String to=jo.getString("to");

             tv.setText("Message "+message+"/n"+"from "+from+"/n"+"to "+to);



             tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);

         }catch(Exception e){

             System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                tv.setText(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                System.out.println("Response from php"+response);
         }

    }
}
```

Here is the php side code

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$obj = new stdClass();

$obj->message="hello";
$obj->from="pratik";
$obj->to="server";

echo json_encode($obj);
?>
```

I am getting the error cannot convert json to string.[image]

Comment: Open http://10.0.2.2/jsondemo.php in your browser and look into the source-code. I guess you'll see some error message. Fix it.

Comment: I fixed it and now i am getting some other wierd output

Comment: output is fine on browser now but on app its still not coming

Comment: @Pratik the code you've posted looks like it has nothing to do with the output or your comments.  Please update your post, or close this question and ask a new one

Comment: john i hav added the output after editing php what i m getting on browser and on my app as well can u please figure out whats prob

Comment: I have really messed up . Getting d output correctly . I used tv.setText twice and 2nd one was giving me wrong output. I m in hurry probably tats y i m screwing it. Thx for d help neways

Comment: @Praktik: Add your solution / explanation as an answer below and accept it later as the correct answer. That's how this site works (and it's not problem to do so), thank you for your help!

Comment: Please take 5 minutes to accept answers to your old questions... it's kind of a slap in the face to the users here who spend their time trying to help you.

Comment: ok. I didnt mean any insult to ne one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the line 
tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
from the code.
It finally worked.!!!

tv.setText("Message "+message+"/n"+"from "+from+"/n"+"to "+to);
That was getting overwritten by  tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);

Comment: You can also write like this `tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + EntityUtils.toString(he));`